# warning: received memory warning level 1 and crashes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, memory-management

I've been researching this throughout SO and some people said that this error is fine as long as the apps doesn't crash.

My app gets this error and after this when I try to tap on a row for a cell (calling didSelectRowAtIndexPath) it crashes. And it gives me an error UIImage sent message to deallocated message. I am guessing that this is because of the memory warning it has freed up some UIView's and therefore it crashes.

Why is this and how do I fix this? I've been debugging this for quite some time, using instruments, profiling, etc and had no luck.
I'd like to post some code, but don't know which one to post.

Comment: Are you using [NSZombiesEnabled](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/home/2009/2/6/nszombie-and-xcode-oh-my.html) to track exactly where the error came up? If so, post some code for the part of didSelectRowAtIndexPath that sends messages to that UIImage.

Comment: I am using NSZombiesEnabled and when it crashes it points out to main.m, specifically   int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"CVore", nil);

Comment: Some of your code can help us.. Try posting some code in your didSelectRowAtIndex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have failed to retain something you cared about. From your message, I would suspect the object is a `UIImage`. Start by running the Static Analyzer and see if you're unretaining something obvious. Then inspect your ivars, particularly ones that are related to images. Make sure you access your ivars using accessors and not directly (except in init, the accessors themselves and dealloc). Make sure your object properties are defined with "retain".

You can use the "Zombies" instrument to help you track down which object is under-retained.

Comment: I have enabled NSZombie and I dont have any UIImage in my apps.. this is why I am pulling my hair out... The closest I have to an UIImage is a TTImageView

Comment: Well, TTImageView almost certainly has a UIImage inside of it, so that's a good place to look. You're probably under-retaining it. You should also make sure that you're setting all you IBOutlets to `nil` in `viewDidUnload`. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmNibObjects.html

Comment: should I be setting the IBOutlet to nil in viewDidUnload or dealloc?

Comment: also one more issue is that I don't know how to reproduce this error.. and one more thing this occurs more often when the app is run in the device and not the simulator.. also when there's only this app running as the only single sole app running.. I don't think that it ever crashes

Comment: You should set the IBOutlet properties to nil (self.label=nil) in viewDidUnload. You should be releasing the IBOutlet ivar ([_label release]) in dealloc. If you want to test low memory conditions in the simulator, use Hardware>Simulate Memory Warning.

Answer (score 0):

by one of your comments, it is very clear that the issue is with memory management and releasing your objects.... I suggest you to go a bit deep into your code and find out the code snippets where you are releasing you objects(or allocating them)... It can also be due to the fact that you are not at all releasing your objects after allocating and the processor trying to kill your app due to the lack of memory...And by the way, this kind of erros suck your time a lot... good luck...

Comment: I agree with your last sentence, it sucks big time..I've spend the last 3 days trying to find this error... I think testing takes a bit more longer than writing the apps itself